# how do I get my program to close once finished in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a number guessing game and once you have guessed the number it will say well done but idle stays open, how do I get it to close?

Comment: IDLE is a code editor; it runs independently of the programs you write.   It sounds like you want to run your programs with the Python executable directly.  Something like `$ python my_program.py`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import sys

...

if number == secret_number:
    print("well done")
    sys.exit() # Exit from Python
```

You don't want your IDLE to exit right after you guess the number, because you won't have enough time to read the 'well done' prompt. 
What could you do? Well, one idea is to just pause the program briefly before exiting:

```
import sys
import time
...
if number == secret_number:
    print("well done")
    time.sleep(5) #Pause for 5 seconds 
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

On windows, you can quit the interpreter with `CTRL-z` and on linux/mac you can quit with `CTRL-D`.  If you type `exit`, it will tell you exactly what to do.

If you are not running interactively (i.e. by running `python your_script.py`) the code will just end when it's reached the bottom of the file.

If you actually do need to interact with the interpreter while you are running your code, you can use `input` (or `raw_input`, depending on the python version) for fetching information from simple prompts, or the `code` module for more complex interactions.

Comment: Thanksyou to miprog12

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make **IDLE** close when the program is done, there are a number of means of doing it. These are two ways of quitting the python shell without needing to import any additional modules. All you need to do is add one line at the end of your program.

```
quit()
```

you alternatively can use

```
exit()
```

Both of these options utilize the class `Quitter(builtins.object) in module _sitebuiltins`
When either of these lines are run, the shell will prompt

> "The program is still running!
>   
> Are you sure you want to kill it?"

When you click "OK" the shell closes. In addition, if you decide that you do not want the shell window to close, you can then simply hit "Cancel", and the shell window will remain open.
Type `help(quit)` in the shell for more information on this feature.